# Flask app config.py vs dotenv to access environment variables

Tags: python, flask

Hi I am relatively new to programming and building my first flask project and I haven't been able to figure out if I should prefer accessing environment variables by using `dotenv` / `load_dotenv` or using them from a config.py file.

I understand the config route is more flexible but my question is specifically to do with environment variables.

Is there a best practice here? [I am building a simple app that will be hosted externally]

Comment: I might be wrong here cause I am new to stack overflow, but chances are your post might be flagged for ask a question that is " opinion based"

Comment: If the answer is, both are fine and there is no best practice, Ill be happy with that and live with the flag! Thanks for the warning though, I am new as well so will see how it goes!

Comment: Take a look at this project as well as his tutorials. https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/tree/v0.23
You will notice that .flaskenv is used for certain things , config.py is used for others

Comment: Thanks. Have looked through this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practices dictate that any value which is secret should not be hard-coded into any files which persist with the project or are checked into source control. Your config file is very likely to be saved in source control, so it should not store secrets, but instead load them from the environment variables set at execution time of the app. For example, let's say you are configuring an SMTP relay:

`MAIL_PORT` is a value that is not secret and not likely to change so it is a good candidate to be set in your config file.

`MAIL_PASSWORD` is a secret value that you do not want saved in your project's repository, so it should be loaded from the host's environment variables.

In this example, your config file might contain entries that look something like this:

```
MAIL_PORT = 465
MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
```

Beyond evaluating whether or not a config value is a secret, also consider how often the value will change and how hard it would be to make that change. Anything hard-coded into your config file will require changing the file and adding a new commit to your source control, possibly even triggering a full CI/CD pipeline process. If the value were instead loaded from environment variables then this value could be changed by simply stopping the application, exporting the new value as an environment variable, and restarting the application.

Dotenv files are simply a convenience for grouping a number of variables together and auto-loading them to be read by your configuration. A `.env` file is not always used as these values can be manually exported when the app is invoked or handled by another system responsible for starting or scaling your application. Do not check `.env` or `.flaskenv` files into your source control.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful way of thinking.